# sending base 64 encoded image to gmail

Tags: java, base64, gmail

i'm trying to send the base 64 encoded image to gmail but i could not able to see the original image.
   i can only able to see the encoded text format.
   i want to see the original image in gmail but i don't know how to show the original image in gamil. i want to show the html format. method name is email sender

```
private void emailSender(CompanyInfo companyInfo) {
     final String username = "rk.ramesh0609@gmail.com";
        final String password = "#######";

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //TLS
        prop.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {


            Map<String, String> inlineImage = new HashMap<String, String>();
             String body = companyInfo.getLocation();
             final Matcher matcher = imgRegExp.matcher( body );
               int i = 0;
               while ( matcher.find() ) {
                      String src = matcher.group();
                      if ( body.indexOf( src ) != -1 ) {
                         String srcToken = "src=\"";
                         int x = src.indexOf( srcToken );
                         int y = src.indexOf( "\"", x + srcToken.length() );
                         String srcText = src.substring( x + srcToken.length(), y );
                         String cid = "image" + i;
                         String newSrc = src.replace( srcText, "cid:" + cid );
                         inlineImage.put( cid, srcText.split( "," )[1] );
                         body = body.replace( src, newSrc );
                         i++;
                      }
                   }




            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("rk.ramesh0609@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("rameshparthi1991@gmail.com")
            );
            message.setSubject("Company info");
            message.setText("Company name:"+companyInfo.getComapanyName()
                    + "\n\n Pic Name:"+companyInfo.getPictureName()
                    + "\n\n Phone Number:"+companyInfo.getPhone()
                    + "\n\n Email:"+companyInfo.getEmail()
                    //+ "\n\n Location:"+companyInfo.getLocation()
                  );


            BodyPart bp = new MimeBodyPart();
            bp.setContent( body, "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" );
            MimeMultipart mmp = new MimeMultipart();
            mmp.addBodyPart( bp );
            Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = inlineImage.entrySet().iterator();
            while ( it.hasNext() ) {
               Entry<String, String> pairs = it.next();
               PreencodedMimeBodyPart pmp = new PreencodedMimeBodyPart( "base64" );
               pmp.setHeader( "Content-ID", "<" + pairs.getKey() + ">" );
               pmp.setDisposition( MimeBodyPart.INLINE );
               pmp.setText( pairs.getValue() );
               mmp.addBodyPart( pmp );
            }
            message.setContent( mmp );

            Transport.send(message,message.getAllRecipients());

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Comment: please provide minimum and complete code sample to reproduce your issue

Comment: i updated full code

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Gmail does not support the use of Base64 encoded images within HTML emails. While Base64 encoding allows for embedding image data directly within the HTML markup, Gmail may not consistently render these images. It's important to note that email clients can have varying levels of support for different features, and Gmail's limitations are in place to ensure security, maintain a consistent user experience, and prevent potential abuse of the platform.

You can [check](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.caniemail.com%2Ffeatures%2Fimage-base64%2F&psig=AOvVaw1BRQawIFnuhlEZYjik2NQV&ust=1686811573678000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBEQjRxqFwoTCJCC5PeUwv8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE) the base 64 support table.